# "File In Use" error on Windows VirtualBox

Tags: windows, nginx, vagrant, virtualbox, file-in-use

Using Vagrant on a Windows Virtualbox, I'm receiving the error "File in Use" whenever I try to delete an asset from a shared folder on the Host OS or change its filename. This occurs after I load a file/asset through Nginx.

*Windows Error*

> File In Use
>   The action can't be completed because the file is open in VBoxHeadless Close the file and try again.

Also moving/deleting the file within the Guest OS fails:

```
$ mv test.css test2.css
mv: cannot move `test.css' to `tests2.css': Text file busy
$ rm test.css
rm: cannot remove `test.css': Text file busy
```

Answer (score 4):

Just leaving this here for any future readers. I found that the Nginx configurations `open_file_cache` & `sendfile` were the culprits, and after turning these off during development, removed the error.

*Nginx.conf*

```
open_file_cache off;
sendfile off;
```

Comment: Just removing `sendfile on` (the default value is `off`) worked for me, as indicated in the [Vagrant docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/virtualbox.html#caveats). I knew about this issue by reading this page before, but couldn't associate it to the "busy file" error outputed on my terminal until I found this SO answer. Thank you @Ricky Boyce.

Comment: Use `EnableSendfile Off` on apache. ([docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#enablesendfile))